# Can I still compile code requiring .net 4.0 developer pack?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to compile an old program, I downloaded the source code, It was a bunch of .cs files. When I opened it up in VSStudio and tried to compile it, I got this error:

> The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

After doing some research, some have had success compiling this on an older version of visual studio. I am going to try that now,

But does anyone know if I can still even compile this code anymore?

Compiling in VisualStudio 2022 with .NET 4.8

Comment: did you install the .net framework sdk with visual studio?

Comment: It should be rather painless to upgrade to .NET 4.8.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any others questions. If it works, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 5):

You can see from [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies#net-framework-4):

> Starting with Visual Studio 2022, Visual Studio no longer includes
> .NET Framework components for .NET Framework 4.0 - 4.5.1 because these
> versions are no longer supported. Visual Studio 2022 and later
> versions can't build apps that target .NET Framework 4.0 through .NET
> Framework 4.5.1. To continue building these apps, you can use Visual
> Studio 2019 or an earlier version.

You can refer to this page to migrate earlier versions of .NET Framework to .NET Framework 4.8.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/